# Could the prophecy in The Cursed Child refer to the resurrection of Voldemort in GOF?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, prophecy

Could the prophecy in *The Cursed Child* refer to the events in *The Goblet of Fire*?

> **“When spares are spared,
>
>  when time is turned,
>
>  when unseen children murder their fathers,
>
>  then will the Dark Lord return."**
>  
>  1. Cedric was the spare.
>  2. Time is turned in PoA which leads to Pettigrew going into hiding and eventually bring back Voldemort.
>  3. Crouch Jr killed his father.

Comment: Cedric was not spared in real timeline. Crouch was not unseen.

Comment: A wiser approach is, not to link TCD with canon works of HP.

Comment: Unfortunately, *Cursed Child* is canon. JKR wrote much of the story it was based on, and I am sure the major plot events were nigh-identical.

Comment: Cursed Child was such a waste of my time...

Comment: @Aegon crouch jr was unseen - he was at times invisible and at other times in disguise as moody. :)

Comment: @RedCaio I don't think that unseen meant literally unseen. I believe unseen children meant the children who were not born in the timeline they were in. E.g. Albus being there to influence events of Harry's years at Hogwarts

Comment: And the spare was not spared!

Comment: I think you meant Spared as killing or sparing their souls from their bodies...

Comment: You probably shouldn't place the bulk of your question in a spoiler block

Comment: Cursed Child, is frankly a cursed child of the Harry Potter series.

Answer (score 2):

## Entirely possible, but it could also refer to TCC

(warning: TCC spoilers)

This prophecy could also be referring to when Albus and Scorpius went back in time. Line by line:

- **When spares are spared**

Cedric is referred to as a 'spare', and when Albus/Scorpius save Cedric, Voldemort was never defeated.

- **when time is turned**

Albus and Scorpius have to travel in time to save Cedric

- **when unseen children murder their fathers**

Indirectly, Albus kills Harry by time-travelling under the Invisibility CLoak, and letting Voldemort not be defeated

- **then will the Dark Lord return**

He returns when the above events happen.